# How to sort a multi-variate grouped data?

Tags: python, pandas

The data I am working with has the **ratings** of **household services** for different **cities**.

Running the code below groups this data based upon the services in each city and finds the total ratings for that particular service.

```
grouped_services_df = df.groupby(["City", "Services"])
total_ratings = grouped_services_df.agg({"Ratings": np.sum})
total_ratings
```

I am trying to find the highest rated service in each city. So is there a way to sort the ratings of services for each city and not for the whole grouped dataframe?

Comment: Add a sample of the data to your question

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Copy `print(df.head())` and paste it in your question

Comment: I tried that and it was too much of a mess to make sense of. Is there a way in which I can print a table?